# How get the selected item in option angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have a `dropdown` that fills with some item of type `ObjectA`.

**item.component.html:**

```html
<label>items list:
    <select formControlName="itemsCtl" (change)="onChange()">
        <option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

In my reactive forms I need to have the selected item but when I searched a lot on the Internet I found the code for my purpose:

**item.component.ts:**

```
selectedItem : ObjectA;
...
onChange()
{  
    this.selectedItem = this.factorForm.controls['itemsCtl'].value;
}
```

but when I get the selected item it is as `[object object]` while I need to have selected item as `ObjectA`. how I can have selected item as `ObjectA` or even how I can convert `[object object]` to `ObjectA`?

Using `Angular` 5.0.1.

Comment: Your `ObjectA` is in "TypeScript land". `[object object]` is (as far as I understand) in JavaScript. There's no contradiction here.

Comment: so how I can convert [object object] to ObjectA? @Amit

Comment: Where *exactly* do you see the `[object object]` output?

Comment: Please could you show what exactly do you have in (itemList)

Comment: when I run console.log(this.factorForm.controls['itemsCtl'].value); I see that the output is [object object] @serpent5

Comment: sure, I get the list via a http service:

getItems() : Promise<ObjectA[]>{

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl).toPromise().then(res => res as ObjectA[]).catch(this.handleError);

  }
@yash_DedSec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ngValue directive instead of value.

```
    <option  *ngFor="let item of itemList"  [ngValue]="item"   >{{item.label}}</option>
```

Comment: thank you so much, now I have selectedItem as a type of ObjectA @Alexander Poshtaruk

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not really sure about what is the structure of your (itemList) or your (ObjectA)

For that I need a little bit more information.

Instead if your method is not working try this:

```
<label>items list:
<select formControlName="itemsCtl" (change)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="someVar">
    <option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item">{{item.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your function:

```
selectedItem : ObjectA;
someVar: any;
...
onChange()
{  
    this.selectedItem = this.factorForm.controls['itemsCtl'].value;
    console.log(someVar);
}
```

See what output this gets.

Hope all this helps!